# Java files are not compliling

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, javac

I have deploy my java code on AWS cloud, when I compile it on windows through terminal, I just have to use the command.

```
javac mainApp.java
```

it automatically create .class files of all other classes, lets say I have another class

```
class newProcessClass
```

who's variable is in mainApp.java, on EC2 when I compile it, it is giving me the error

```
error: could not find this symbol
          newProcessClass npc = new newProcessClass();
```

same for the other classes. how can I compile it, and run it.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I think that might be caused by classpath issue,

So please make sure current path(.) is under your classpath.

- You can do this by type the follow into your terminal(pay attention to the little dot please!)

  export CLASSPATH=.;$CLASSPATH
- If you would like to persistent this setting and avoid set this everytime, you'd better add it to your .bashrc file.
- And then when you run the class via **java** command, please also specify classpath as below

  java -cp . mainApp

Comment: Thanks, But same problem remains.

Comment: If all the java files are in the same directory, you can try javac  *.java

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use Maven for the life cycle for application java and when you compiled the mainApp.java this action has that compile all file. you can get me more information of error stack?. For other side I think that is best that you use Maven. Best regards